# NSWindow IBOutlet is not remaining synchronous

Tags: xcode, macos

Mac OS X code using `IBOutlet` that does not update continuously during a function but does update at the end of the function.

I am using Xcode 10.2.1.  I have tried display, update, `displayIfNeeded`, and forcing to main thread using `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

```
- (IBAction) Test:(id)sender
{
int  k;
int j = [obsInput intValue];
kvoObjONE *one = [[kvoObjONE alloc] init];
kvoObjTWO *two = [[kvoObjTWO alloc] init];
one.x = j;
[one addObserver:two forKeyPath:@"x" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

for (k=0; k<10; k++)
{
    one.x = one.x + 10;
    usleep(100000);
    [echInput setIntValue: one.x];
 //   [echInput setIntValue: 34+k];
    [outFromIn setIntValue: two.y];
    NSLog(@"x %d  y %d ", one.x, two.y);
    NSLog(@"   echInput %d", [echInput intValue]);

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(WSdisplay) withObject:@"nil" waitUntilDone:YES];
}
[one removeObserver:two forKeyPath:@"x"];

};

- (void)WSdisplay
{
//   [[self.window contentView] setNeedsDisplay:YES];

//  [self.window displayIfNeeded];
[self.window update];
[self.window display];

NSLog(@"display message 2\n");
}
```

I expect my `IBOutlets` (echInput and outFromIn) to change in my `NSWindow` each time through the for loop.  This doesn't occur each time through the loop but does occur after the removeObserver statement.
 I expect console to show values of one.x, two.y, echInput and display message for each loop and this does occur.

Answer (score 0):

> I have [...] forcing to main thread using performSelectorOnMainThread

Your `Test:` function is *already* running on the main thread, which is your problem. You're blocking the main thread, and UI updates won't occur until you unblock it (i.e. when returning from your `Test:` function).

You can run your code on a thread instead, e.g.:

```
- (IBAction) Test:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // Current body of `Test:` function here
```

Now, inside that `dispatch_async` block you can't touch your UI objects. You will need to wrap any such calls in another `dispatch`, this time back onto the main thread e.g.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [echInput setIntValue: one.x];
    [outFromIn setIntValue: two.y];
    NSLog(@"x %d  y %d ", one.x, two.y);
    NSLog(@"   echInput %d", [echInput intValue]);
});
```